# What causes light to travel through a curved fountain of water?

Tags: gravity, visible-light, laser

Today I observed a tilted fountain spurting water upward (the water fell smoothly; no detectable turbulence). A colored light was shown upward into the water as it left its source. This light traveled through the water and was reflected from the ground wherever the water landed. **Why?** I suspect the water trapped some portion of the light and acted as a mirror. **Why should this be the case?** Especially due to the non-linear motion of the water.

[image]

Comment: The water column is acting like a multimode optical fiber or if you prefer, light pipe.  Google it.

Comment: "...and it, of course, fell in a parabolic curve". It's a pet peeve of mine when people say "of course" or "obviously", etc... Especially when they are wrong. First: The curve you drew does not look parabolic. Second: Spurting water does not travel in a parabola, air resistance is non-negligible.

Comment: You're right. Would parabolic-like be a better fit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Total Internal reflection is what causes optical fibers to propagate beams with minimal distortion

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_internal_reflection

At the small incident angles the beam hits the wall between the two different refraction indices, the light is reflected completely, which from the perspective of geometric rays, keep the beam enclosed as long as the fiber doesn't get bent into a high angle